# ruby initialize method - purpose of initialize arguments

Tags: ruby, oop, initialization, arguments

Im a bit confused on the initialize method. I understand that it is automatically called when you do `Person.new` and you add the arguments to it like `Person.new("james")`.  What I dont understand is, why would you have instance variables in your initialize method that are not an used as an  argument also. Is it so you can use them later on after the instance has been created? 
See below. What reason is there to have `@age` in the initialize method but not as an argument. thanks.

```
class Person

  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @age = age
  end
```

Comment: `Is it so you can use them later on after the instance has been created?` Yep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an instance variable in any method in your class.

`initialize` is a method that is executed immediately after calling `Person.new`.

All external data for **new** object is passed through the arguments of `.new(args)`.

Your line `@age = age` - it's the same that `@age = nil`.

This is due to the fact that `age` is absent in the arguments of `initialize`.

Also you have `attr_accessor :age`.

It's equal, that you have methods:

```
def age
  @age
end

def age=(age)
  @age = age
end
```

So you can set instance variable like this:

```
john = Person.new('John')
p john.age #=> nil

john.age = 5
p john.age #=> 5
```

Comment: thanks. so as i have `attr_accessor :age`, does that mean that i don't need to include `@age = age` in the initialize method, if i dont want to initialize age straight away?

Comment: Yes, in this case, you can remove this line.

Comment: What other cases would I keep it?

Comment: For example it's a rule in your team to write all variables in `initialize` or you use method as @iGian show

Answer (score 0):

The instance variables declared inside your initialize method only need to be those which you want to set during initialization. In your `Person` class example, you wouldn't need to set @age in initialization (it actually would throw an error as you currently have it).

```
  class Person

    attr_accessor :name, :age

    def initialize(name)
      @name = name
    end

    def birthday
      if @age.nil?
        @age = 1
      else
        @age += 1
      end
    end
  end
```

Hopefully, this helps. If the initialize method doesn't have an age set, you can still use/set age in other methods. In this case, the first time the `Person.birthday` method is called, it would set their @age to 1, and then increment it from there.

Answer (score 0):

For example if you need to call a method to assign a value to the instance variable while instantiating the object.

This is silly, but gives an idea:

```
class Person

  attr_accessor :name, :age

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @age = random_age
  end

  def random_age
    rand(1..100)
  end

end

jack = Person.new('jack')
p jack.age #=> 29
```